# Display an initialized array of structure in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, struct

I have a bulk of code like this:

```
struct SoccerTeam
{
    string teamName;
    int totalGame;
    SoccerPlayer playerStore[PLAYERS] = { { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 }, { "NONE", 0 } };
};

//Function prototypes.
void showStats(SoccerTeam team[], bool);
void getTeamInfo(SoccerTeam team[]);

//Main function.
int main()
{
    bool flag = true;
    SoccerTeam leagueTeam[TEAM] = { { "NONE", 0, "NONE"}, { "NONE", 0, "NONE"}, { "NONE", 0, "NONE"}, { "NONE", 0, "NONE"} };

    //Call the function to print out the content of the initialized array.
    showStats(leagueTeam, flag);

    //Call the function to ask the user to enter values into the array.
    getTeamInfo(leagueTeam);

    //Call the show stat function again with user's input.
    showStats(leagueTeam, flag);
}
```

And I'm trying to display the initialized array to the screen, by using the function:

```
//Function that displays the contents of the array to the screen.
void showStats(SoccerTeam team[], bool flag)
{
    double averageG = 0.00;

    cout << "Data After Initialization:" << endl << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < TEAM; i++)
    {
        cout << "The team: " << team[i].teamName << " has played " << team[i].totalGame << " games." << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < PLAYERS; j++)
        {
            cout << right << setw(20) << "Player: " << team[j].playerStore->playerName << " has " << team[j].playerStore->goalScore << " goals. " << endl;
            averageG = team[j].playerStore->goalScore / team[j].totalGame;
            cout << "The average goals are: " << averageG << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And the output only shows the first and third line. I don't know what's wrong with it. I'm new to structure and yet I have a hard time understanding this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your error code clearly indicates:

0xc0000094 Integer divide by zero exception

Coming from this line:

```
averageG = team[j].playerStore->goalScore / team[j].totalGame;
```

Also, this doesn't look right:

```
SoccerTeam leagueTeam[TEAM] = { { "NONE", 0, "NONE"}, { "NONE", 0, "NONE"}, { "NONE", 0, "NONE"}, { "NONE", 0, "NONE"} };
```